# how to sent hindi or other language to another page with rich text editor

Tags: javascript, php, rich-text-editor

When I am Input This **"आप सभी दोस्तों को नमस्कार"** and send with post method. this text show like this **"à¤†à¤ª à¤¸à¤­à¥€ à¤¦à¥‹à¤¸à¥à¤¤à¥‹à¤‚ à¤•à¥‹ à¤¨à¤®à¤¸à¥à¤•à¤¾à¤°"** but i want to show sent data as it is.

[Input Data Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkrv3.png)

[Send Data Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv4eH.png)

Comment: should change CHARACTER SET utf8 in your PHPMYADMIN, https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403914/default-mysql-character-set-and-collation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am persian and i know this problem finely :
use this line in   :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in submission page and show page

Comment: use it in <head> ...  </head>

Answer (score 0):

You should always specify the encoding used for an HTML page. If you don't,so will cause browsers to guess the encoding, which can lead to cross-site scripting attacks if they guess incorrectly.

Always declare the encoding of your document using a meta element with a charset attribute, or using the `http-equiv` and content attributes (called a pragma directive). The declaration should fit completely within the first 1024 bytes at the start of the file, so it's best to put it immediately after the opening head tag.
for exam

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hi"> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
.....
</head>
<body>
........
</body>
</html>
```